How to expose MQTT service running in K3s using domain name with Ingress and make it accessible publicly?
I am trying to expose an MQTT service running in a K3s cluster to the internet using a domain name. However, I am encountering issues where the service is not accessible publicly. When I attempt to connect to the MQTT broker using an ESP32 device via the domain mqtt.example.com, I get a "connection refused" error.
Here are the relevant configurations I am using:

Deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mqtt
  namespace: mqtt-dev
  labels:
    app: mqtt
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mqtt
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mqtt
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mqtt
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 1883
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 1883
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5


Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt
  namespace: mqtt-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mqtt
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1883
    targetPort: 1883
    nodePort: 30083


Ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mqtt-ingress
  namespace: mqtt-dev
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: mqtt.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mqtt
            port:
              number: 1883
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mqtt.example.com




Troubleshooting and Observations:

The kubectl get svc command often shows EXTERNAL-IP as none or pending.
I tried using various service types such as LoadBalancer and NodePort, but neither resolved the issue.
Connecting to the broker using the domain name (mqtt.example.com) results in a "connection refused" error on the ESP32 client.
The Ingress uses the Traefik controller configured in the K3s cluster.
I verified that the DNS is correctly resolving mqtt.example.com to the cluster's external IP.

Questions:

What is the correct configuration for exposing a TCP-based service like MQTT using Ingress in K3s?
Is there a specific setup required for Traefik to handle TCP traffic (instead of HTTP) for this use case?
How can I ensure the service is publicly accessible over the internet using the domain name?

Any advice or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78261779/configuring-k3s-and-traefik-ingress-to-expose-tcp-port-for-ssh it does something quite similar for an Ingress
Note that with k3s, you should be able to connect to the port 1883 of your service if use LoadBalancer instead of NodePort , remove nodePort: 30083  and possibly set allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true too. And ofcourse remove any firewall rules on the host that could block port 1883

To expose none HTTP services on Kubernetes Ingress is the wrong approach.
Ingress using HTTP Hostname based proxying, but MQTT does not include the Hostname in the protocol connect packet, so the controller has no way to determine how to route the traffic to the correct pod
The correct way to expose these is to use Service of the type LoadBalancer (rather than NodePort or ClusterIP). But a LoadBalancer is going to need a pool of IP addresses to use to expose ports.
You can expose MQTT over WebSockets using Ingress as that bootstraps as HTTP.
